# DotTrace on Remoting Proxy

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I have a WebAPI project running on local machine that is calling server side codes via remote proxy (local machine) on service layer. The profiler was able to trace the hotspot but up to service layer only and the hotspot is all pointing to methods calling server side methods.

**How can I let the profiler trace the bottlenecks in server side codes?**

**Things to note:**

```
1. Controller and service layer = .Net4.5
2. Server Side = .Net 3.5
3. Remote Proxy is using local web service.
```

**Things I did**

```
1. Profile the whole project
2. Profile the web service
3. Run the remote agent locally
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple dotTrace standalone at the same time. One dotTrace for each side (WebAPI and server). If you attach to the server side process, you will be able to find the hotspots

Comment: Do you have a link on how to do it?

Comment: Here you have all the options : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Profiling_Different_Kinds_of_Applications.html and you need to start 2 instances of dotTrace

Answer (score 0):

What server do you use to host the server-side code? If it is IIS or IIS Express, you need to profile it from the corresponding section of dotTrace Home.
Anyway, you can start profiling from ".NET Process" section of dotTrace Home - in this mode any managed application that is started after clicking Run will be profiled (you just need to select the right application in profiling controller and get a snapshot). See this page for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__dotNET_Process.html